# ngRoute passing parameter does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm passing `/?preview=true` in my function and catch in app.js `$route.current.params.preview` like that. But when I output `$route.current.params.preview` in console log, it's undefined. Please help me how to solve that error.

**Below is blah.js** to go `http://localhost:9000/?preview=true` like that.

```
    var buildLangPathUrl = function () {
        return LANG_PATH ? LANG_PATH + '/' : '/';
    };

    this.openFrontPageWithPreview = function () {
        $rootScope.openPage(buildLangPathUrl() + '?preview=true');
    };
```

app.js

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (user) {
        var path = $location.path();
        $rootScope.showIndex =
            path === LANG_PATH + '/';
        if ($rootScope.showIndex) {
            pageService.setPageMetaData('');
            if($rootScope.loggedUser) {
                console.log($route.current.params.preview); << 'undefined'
                if (!$route.current.params.preview) {
                    routeService.openSuggestedJobs()
                } 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just use `$routeParams` instead of `$route.current.params`.

Comment: but I declare ``$route`` in controller instead.

Comment: What's the other use of `$route` in your controller besides getting the current params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `$location.search()` as setter/getter for query params object.

Or `$routeParams.search` object

```
if ($location.search().preview) {
// or
if ($routeParams.search) {
```

Be sure to inject whichever one you use